# using joins how to compare 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

**Table1**:

```
ID  Name
1   OS
2   Harddisk
3   RAM
4   WINDOWS
5   LINUX
6   SOLARIS
7   MAC
8   UNIX
9   DCCI
```

**Table2**:

```
ID Table1_ID   Table1_component
1   1            4
2   1            5
3   1            6
4   1            7
5   1            8
6   1            9
```

I want to join the above 2 tables and I need output put as

```
Table1_ID   Table1_component
    OS          Windows
    OS          Linux
    OS          SOLARIS
    OS          MAC
    OS          UNIX
    OS          DCCI
```

Please help me, instead of numbers in `Table 2` I need names from `Table1`

Comment: Please post what code you have tried and explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to JOIN on `Table1` twice to get the result:

```
select t1.name as table1_id,
  c.name as Table1_component
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.table1_id
inner join table1 c
  on t2.Table1_component = c.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73aac/4)